# get the names of txt files from assets folder into a list

Tags: android, file-io

I'm trying to get a list of the name of txt files stored in my assets folder but when i call

`String[] files = assetManager.list("/assets");`

i get an exception

```
01-13 15:48:44.819: E/AndroidRuntime(6754): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.readd/com.example.readd.MainActivity}:
```

i suppose i have and error with the parameter "/assets" in list("/assets")., but dont have idea how to solve it.

**EDIT** in my assets folder i got just raw files without subfolders

text1.txt

text2.txt

text3.txt

i've try also assetManager.list(""); but when i try to set a txtView with the name of the(lets say) first file tt.setText(files[0]);, it give's me images as a result, and i dont have file like that in my assets

**EDIT2**

```
            AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    try {

        String[] files = assetManager.list("");

        InputStream stream = getAssets().open("text1.txt");

        tt.setText(files[0]);//here i get images(as String not real images) as result
        }
```

Comment: post full stacktrace.

Comment: what kind of images ?

Comment: just as string ... "images"

Comment: so there is a file or a folder named "images" in your assets folder. (probably a folder, by the looks of it)

Comment: i used for loop to see whole list... and its consists |images|sound|text1.txt|text2.txt|text3.txt|webkit|, so there are my files but from where came those other three

Comment: Apparently this happens. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761008/assets-images-sounds-and-webkit

Comment: comes from here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/res/assets apparently

Comment: the solution: i used getBaseContext() and i have created new SUB folder assets which contains my files... thanks a lot for the discussion :) appreciate that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

if you want to get what's inside a subfolder pass the name of the subfolder:

```
String[] files = assetManager.list("mySubFolder");
```

Comment: i try to do that(list("")), but when i try to set  a txtView with the name of the(lets say) first file `tt.setText(files[0]);`, it give's me **images** as a result, and i dont have file like that in my assets

Comment: only you know wha's  inside your assets folder, but that's the way he works

Comment: Can you show me the way your are getting the AssetManager object?

Comment: `AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();`

Comment: i used for loop to see whole list... and its consists |images|sound|text1.txt|text2.txt|text3.txt|webkit|, so there are my files but from where came those other three????

Comment: if you are using getApplicationContext() probably you are inside an Activity or you should be able to access the Activity's context. Try using it and see if it makes difference

Comment: **the solution**: i used getBaseContext() and i have created new SUB folder assets which contains my files... thanks a lot for the discussion :) appreciate that!

Comment: There is a way to get the folder names that are in the assets folder?

Comment: You could give File#getParentName a try

Comment: Using an empty string it is possible to get the name of the folders in "assets" (but take a care; because it adds 3 additional folders: images, sounds and webkit).